# multicasting on linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, multicast

I am testing a simple multicast application on linux. I got it working on my pc by doing the following:

- disabling the firewall
- running the command route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0

if you are interested in the details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697534/multicast-ip-address-blocked-in-call-to-recvfrom) post

why are these two steps required? is there an alternative.

i am testing the code on localhost.

on another pc I tried running the program after disabling the firewall. it did not work.
when I run the route command I get the following message

```
route: netmask 0fffffff doesn't make sense with host route
Usage: route [-nNvee] [-FC] [<AF>]           List kernel routing tables
   route [-v] [-FC] {add|del|flush} ...  Modify routing table for AF.

   route {-h|--help} [<AF>]              Detailed usage syntax for specified AF.
   route {-V|--version}                  Display version/author and exit.

    -v, --verbose            be verbose
    -n, --numeric            don't resolve names
    -e, --extend             display other/more information
    -F, --fib                display Forwarding Information Base (default)
    -C, --cache              display routing cache instead of FIB

<AF>=Use '-A <af>' or '--<af>'; default: inet
List of possible address families (which support routing):
inet (DARPA Internet) inet6 (IPv6) ax25 (AMPR AX.25) 
netrom (AMPR NET/ROM) ipx (Novell IPX) ddp (Appletalk DDP) 
x25 (CCITT X.25)
```

what is the solution?

Comment: Please post this question on superuser.com

Comment: @Anand: We have a migration system, if it belongs to superuser, it will be migrated, he should NOT post it there, it will be moved for him.

Comment: who is responsible for migrating the question

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: users with 3000+ of reputation can vote to close questions, and one of the reasons to choose can be to migrate the question to another site (superuser, in this case). It needs 5 people to vote, for the question to be migrated. If you ask a question which should obviously be moved, it will be. His recommendation to ask your question there is not good, in the meaning that if you do so, when this one will be moved, there will be a duplicate on the other site. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29127/how-to-make-migration-more-clear-to-new-users for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it to work without the route command.
just some firewall configuration problem.

i saw this recommendation to use route command for running ping on a multicast address. it is not required here.